# Go to row in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I go to a certain row in Excel 2007?

Amazingly, I can't find the answer to this simple question on Google. Ctrl+G doesn't do it. When I enter a row number under "Reference", it tells me the reference is not valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to go to (meaning select) a specific row, you can type, for example 10:10 in the Goto box ( <kbd>F5</kbd>) to select row 10.  You need the colon for it to work.  Also, you can go to multiple rows like 10:12.

Comment: This is actually a more helpful answer than the one I originally picked. Thanks.

Comment: this also works in OpenOffice/LibreOffice

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>F5</kbd> then your cell number.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> does the same thing even though you are saying it doesn't work.  You have to enter an entire cell number when you use these methods, not just the row number.

Answer (score 6):

To go to the first cell in a row just press Ctrl+G and A(row number here)
so for the 5th row Ctrl+g A5 in the reference and ok.

On a further note, the reference will bring you to a specific cell. So you can do G18 if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2007, click in reference bar, Reference changes to a selection of the current cell reference, type your cell number and then hit enter.  E.G.  go to row 235,  type A235, hit enter.